# 課題がわけわかりません、助けてください。

Tags: python

> local_character_rdf.json を読んで，都道府県名をキーに，その都道府県に所属する ご当地キャラクターの名前の集合（セット）を値とする辞書を作成しなさい．
> それを使って，都道府毎にご当地キャラクターの数を調べて，多い順に表示するプログラムを作成しなさい．

というものなのですが、この通り、

```
import json

with open("local_character_rdf.json") as f:
    local_characters = json.load(f)

pref = ("北海道","青森県","岩手県","宮城県","秋田県","山形県","福島県","茨城県","栃木県",
"群馬県","埼玉県","千葉県","東京都","神奈川県","新潟県","富山県","石川県","福井県",
"山梨県","長野県","岐阜県","静岡県","愛知県","三重県","滋賀県","京都府","大阪府",
"兵庫県","奈良県","和歌山県","鳥取県","島根県","岡山県","広島県","山口県","徳島県",
"香川県","愛媛県","高知県","福岡県","佐賀県","長崎県","熊本県","大分県","宮崎県",
"鹿児島県","沖縄県")
sale={0}

for character in local_characters.values():
    for i in range(0,53):
         if character["http://imi.ipa.go.jp/ns/core/rdf#都道府県"][0]["value"] == pref[i]:
              sale.add(
         character["http://imi.ipa.go.jp/ns/core/rdf#名称"][0]["value"])
print(pref[1],len(sale)-1)
```

全くできません。どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　せっかくご質問いただいたところ申し訳ありませんが、いま質問者さんがどこで困っているのかを質問文に書いていただけないでしょうか。たとえばエラーが出ているのであればそのエラーメッセージをコピー＆ペーストしてほしいです。エラーは出ないものの思ったように動かないのであれば、想定する挙動と実際の挙動を両方書いて、その差が分かるようにしてください。今は前提となる文脈しか書かれていなくて、回答者が何を解決すれば良いのか分からない状態です。質問文は後からでも [edit] できます。こちらのヘルプもご覧ください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` を利用する場合。

```py
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open("local_character_rdf.json") as f:
    local_characters = json.load(f)

pref_key = 'http://imi.ipa.go.jp/ns/core/rdf#都道府県'
name_key = 'http://imi.ipa.go.jp/ns/core/rdf#名称'
characters_dict = defaultdict(set)
for v in local_characters.values():
    pref = v[pref_key][0]['value']
    name = v[name_key][0]['value']
    characters_dict[pref].add(name)

characters_dict = dict(characters_dict)

for pref, chars in sorted(characters_dict.items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[1])):
    print(pref, len(chars))

# 東京都 192
# 愛知県 123
# 大阪府 93
# 埼玉県 79
# 神奈川県 74
#       :
#
```

Comment: ありがとうございます（ ;  ; ）